# How to parse string to byte array

Tags: java

I have some string, which I will receive from UI:

```
String str = "12a47b4cea";
```

It represents sequence of hexademical numbers.
How can I convert it into a byte array?

Expected output is:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] {0x12, 0xa4, 0x7b, 0x4c, 0xea };
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Comment: It all that I need, Thanks a lot!